# codeigniter session values are overwritten

Tags: codeigniter

In my view I have the following code:

```
  if (($news['newsvideo'] !="") || ($news['newsvideo'] != NULL)) {

     $newdata4 = array(
     'tablename'  => 'news',
     'recordid'     => $news['newsid'],
     'fieldname' => 'newsid',
     'fieldToUpdate' => 'newsvideo',
     'dpage' => 'news/editNews'
     );

     $this->session->set_userdata($newdata4);
     echo anchor('news/updateOneField', 'Delete Video?','class=btn');
 }

  if (($news['newsvideo_en'] !="") || ($news['newsvideo_en'] != NULL)) {

     $newdata5 = array(
     'tablename'  => 'news',
     'recordid'     => $news['newsid'],
     'fieldname' => 'newsid',
     'fieldToUpdate' => 'newsvideo_en',
     'dpage' => 'news/editNews'
     );

     $this->session->set_userdata($newdata5);
     echo anchor('news/updateOneField', 'Delete Video?','class=btn');
 }
```

Function in my controller is the following:

```
public function updateOneField() 
    {  

        $tablename = $this->session->userdata('tablename');
        $id = $this->session->userdata('recordid');
        $fieldname = $this->session->userdata('fieldname');
        $fieldToUpdate = $this->session->userdata('fieldToUpdate');   
        //$this->newsModel->save(array($fieldToUpdate => ''), $id);        
        //$newsid = $id;

        echo "Table name: ". $tablename . "<br/>";
        echo "Id: " . $id. "<br/>";
        echo "Field name: " . $fieldname. "<br/>";
        echo "Field to update: " . $fieldToUpdate. "<br/>";
        die();
        // destroy the session after the update
        $this->session->unset_userdata('tablename');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('recordid');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('fieldname');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('fieldToUpdate');

        $this->displayEditNewsForm($newsid);
    }
```

Now, if i click on the first link i want to delete newsvideo, when try to update the newsvideo field, newsvideo_en is updated. That means that I overwrite the values of the array later. Does anyone has idea how to avoid that, and to update the correct field?

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Why are you checking for empty AND null?**

```
if (($news['newsvideo_en'] !="") || ($news['newsvideo_en'] != NULL)) {
```

you can probably just use

`if ($news['newsvideo_en'] !=""){`

unless you meant to check if `not empty` *AND* `not null` in which case you want

`if (($news['newsvideo_en'] !="") AND ($news['newsvideo_en'] != NULL)) {`

**2) Why are you telling the script to `die()` before unsetting the session data?**

```
    echo "Table name: ". $tablename . "<br/>";
    echo "Id: " . $id. "<br/>";
    echo "Field name: " . $fieldname. "<br/>";
    echo "Field to update: " . $fieldToUpdate. "<br/>";
    die();//anything below here WILL NOT RUN
    // destroy the session after the update

    //this code will never run...
    $this->session->unset_userdata('tablename');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('recordid');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('fieldname');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('fieldToUpdate');
```

Because the script dies before ever reaching the `unset_userdata` code, the unset never runs. If you want to clear out the session data, you have to get rid of that `die()`.

**3) Why don't you just use POST?**

```
echo form_open("video_edit");

if ($news['newsvideo'] !="") {
    echo form_hidden('fieldToUpdate','newvideo');
}
if ($news['newsvideo_en'] !="") {
    echo form_hidden('fieldToUpdate','newvideo_en');
}
echo form_hidden("tablename","news");
echo form_hidden("recordid",$news['newsid']);
echo form_hidden("fieldname","newsid");
echo form_hidden("dpage","news/editNews");

echo anchor("news/updateOneField", "Delete Video?","class=btn");

echo form_close();
```

Comment: 2) Why are you telling the script to die() before unsetting the session data? Because i wanted to check which field i am updating, since it was always the last one, that is videonews_en

Comment: 3) Why don't you just use POST? When I had one field to update, this function worked like a charm. Problems occur when I add more fields. In other controllers where I have only one field it worked just fine. If I don't find solution for my problem i guess that I will use the post...

Comment: Well, session data is very limited in size (if you aren't using db sessions): "Note: Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed the capacity. The encryption process in particular produces a longer data string than the original so keep careful track of how much data you are storing." - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html Better to use post--session data isn't designed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are right. I will switch the code to post, instead of continuing bumping my head agains the wall.